# How to create system restore point when user log into application and reset PC by that restore point on logout from winforms C# application?

Tags: c#, winforms, kiosk

I have tried to create restore point using below code but it is not working in windows 10:
is there any alternate solution for it? if possible please provide example.

```
        public static bool CreateRestorePoint(string description)
        {
            bool isCreated = true;
            try
            {
                ManagementScope oScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\localhost\\root\\default");
                ManagementPath oPath = new ManagementPath("SystemRestore");
                ObjectGetOptions oGetOp = new ObjectGetOptions();
                ManagementClass oProcess = new ManagementClass(oScope, oPath, oGetOp);

                ManagementBaseObject oInParams =
                     oProcess.GetMethodParameters("CreateRestorePoint");
                oInParams["Description"] = description;
                oInParams["RestorePointType"] = 12; // MODIFY_SETTINGS
                oInParams["EventType"] = 100;

                ManagementBaseObject oOutParams =
                     oProcess.InvokeMethod("CreateRestorePoint", oInParams, null);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                isCreated = !isCreated;
            }
            return isCreated;
        }
```